# Ansible: How to parse an inventory source

Tags: lxc, ansible

I'm following an Ansible tutorial I got from Packt, I reached this part where I've created 3 Ubuntu containers (lxc) and got them up and running. I'm also able to login to each of them.

I've downloaded Ansible by doing: `git clone ansible-git-url` and then sourced it.

My working setup is as follows:
`/home/myuser/code` in here I have 2 folders: `ansible` (the whole git repo) and `ansible_course` where I have 2 files: `ansible.cfg` and `inventory`.

`inventory` contains the following:

```
[allservers]
192.168.122.117 
192.168.122.146
192.168.122.14

[web]
192.168.122.146
192.168.122.14

[database]
192.168.122.117
```

And `ansible.cfg` contains:

```
[root@localhost ansible_course]# cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

Then from this path: `/home/myuser/code/ansible_course` I try to execute the following:

```
$ ansible 192.168.122.117 -m ping -u root
```

The guy from the tutorial does exactly like this, and he gets success response from the `ping`, but I get the following error messages:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 192.168.122.117
```

In the tutorial, he never says that I need to do something special in order to give an `inventory` source, he just says that we need to create an `inventory` file with the IP addresses of the Linux containers that we have.

I mean, he doesn't say that we need to execute a command to set this up.

Comment: Are those HTML `<br>` tags in your ansible.cfg?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yeah, I think I erased them, sometimes i forgot that need to edit some text as code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll probably want to tell ansible where the hosts file is in `ansible.cfg`, e.g.

```
[defaults]
inventory=inventory
```

assuming `inventory` is actually your inventory file.

Comment: this was really usefull, as I said, the guy from the vids never mentioned that. No I was able to pass throght those 4 error messages, but now I am getting the following:

    '[root@localhost ansible_course]# ansible 192.168.122.117 -m ping -u root
192.168.122.117 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}'

Comment: you'll either need to setup public key authentication (a different question) or use `-k` so that Ansible prompts for a password to use for the SSH connection

Answer (score 5):

#### Background

With `ansible` you can either depend on the `ansible.cfg` file to designate the name of the `inventory` file or you can specify it manually like so:

*explicitly told*

```
$ ansible -i inventory -m ping -u root 192.168.122.117
```

*implicitly told through ansible.cfg*

```
$ ansible -m ping -u root 192.168.122.117
```

#### Explicit

For the method where you explicitly tell `ansible` which inventory file to use the usage shows this description for it:

From the `ansible` usage:

```
 -i INVENTORY, --inventory=INVENTORY
          specify inventory host path or comma separated host list.
```

#### Implicit

For the implicit method, you have to be a little bit more versed in Ansible to realize that it works like this. You can use `ansible`'s verbose mode to see more of what it's doing by default:

```
$ ansible -vvv -m ping -u root box-101
...
...
config file = /Users/user1/somedir/ansible.cfg
...
...
Using /Users/user1/somedir/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed /Users/user1/somedir/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
Using module file /Users/user1/projects/git_repos/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
...
...
box-101 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
...
...
```

In the above I'm pinging box-101. You can see these lines show which `ansible.cfg` file is getting used:

> ```
> config file = /Users/user1/somedir/ansible.cfg
> Using /Users/user1/ansible.cfg as config file
> ```

And through this `ansible.cfg` file ultimately which inventory:

> ```
> Parsed /Users/user1/somedir/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
> ```

And it's these options that are directing ansible to the `inventory` file:

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
...
[defaults]
inventory      = inventory
...
```

Comment: thanks for all of this information, I will save it in my notes. I used the implicity way, I think it is easier.