# Ansible: failed to ping a linux container

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, ansible, container

Continuig with my ansible learning, I already fixed how to [Ansible: How to parse an inventory source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458475/ansible-how-to-parse-an-inventory-source) but now I ran into a new problem. He executes the following 2 commands (but im not sure if he does as a normal user or root):

`ssh-add -L`

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

And then he executes the following one, in order to do a ping to one of the 3 linux containers:

`ansible 192.168.122.117 -m ping -u root`

And then he gets a success ping message. But in my case, I get an error message that follows:

`[smartinez@localhost ansible_course]$ ansible 192.168.122.117 -m ping -u root
192.168.122.117 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.117 port 22: No route to host\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}`

I am not sure if I need to create another ssh rsa key only for ansible?
Or if he is running the commands as root, and I need to create an ssh rsa for the root user?

I already tried running the 2 `ssh-add`  commands as `root` but i got: "No such file or directory"

Also, I tried adding -k at the end with both users root and ubuntu, but the result us the same.

Any comment ans suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Your host 192.168.122.117 doesn't exist. Is it a VM? Is the VM booted?

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, it is a linux container, I created 3 of them, all ubuntu. Their ips are the following:
[allservers]
192.168.122.117
192.168.122.146
192.168.122.14. Also those ips are in a file called inventory

Comment: (Could you either edit Qs to mention that the video is not public (paid for?), or include a link to the video?). I don't have a quick checklist for server network troubleshooting, but I can suggest generic steps. Starting inside the linux container: I assume you configured it to cover all the basic network settings, including a route to the internet (a.k.a. "default route" / "default router" / "default gateway"). What is the address of its default router? Can it successfully `ping` it? If you don't get a ping reply, but there's a good entry for it in `ip -4 neigh`, that *might* be ok as well.

Comment: **OH** - but first. Before, you said you could login into the containers. Should I assume you meant something like `lxc-console`?  Or, do you have normal `ssh` working OK, but for some mysterious-seeming reason, `ansible` is not able to connect?

Comment: To be clear: "No route to host" is network troubleshooting territory. That error needs fixing first, and it does not have to do with any of your SSH keys. Of course sometimes the problem to fix is I wrote the wrong IP address somewhere :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi "I assume you configured it to cover all the basic network settings, including a route to the internet " No I havent. There is no such command or comment on that in the (payed) tutorial I am following. Literally, Create the containers, run ssh-rsa config the 2 commands from above, and then he just do a ansible ping to one of the lxc containers

Comment: @grimmjow_sms ok... I apologize for flailing a little: I don't have LXC. You were saying you created them with specific IP addresses? How? My checklist uses the default router for troubleshooting because generally the IP address + default router are configured at the same time. And because generally the objective is to have basic internet access e.g. to be able to download & install additional packages, so I can focus on that first. If you have no default router you have no internet access. Maybe you do have a default router, because LXC guesses it based on other settings?

Comment: `ip -4 route` should show `default via <ip address>`.